# Why is fickler a word?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, comparatives

I just tried to instinctively write "more fickle" because fickle is polysyllabic and would, by tradition, get the "more" comparative form vs the "er" comparative form.  But MS Word dinged me as wrong.  This didn't phase me since Word is frequently wrong, but after a quick double check, it turns out that the comparative form of fickle is indeed "fickler".  Which just sounds hideous to my ear.

After much research, I've come up blank as to why this word seems to be an exception to the rule. Does anyone have any insight into why "fickler" is even a word and why "more fickle" is seemingly incorrect?

Comment: Actually “more fickle” is a much more common comparative expression than “fickler. - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+fickle+than%2C+fickler+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20fickle%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfickler%20than%3B%2Cc0

Comment: MS Word has a reputation of being fickler than most rational reviewers.

Comment: *faze* and *phase* are unrelated, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan (Oxford, 2005) has

> **two-syllable adjectives**
>
> Adjectives ending in *-y* have *-ier* and *-iest.*
>
> *happy happier happiest
>
>   easy easier easiest*
>
> Some other two-syllable adjectives can have *-er* and *-est,* especially adjectives
>   ending in an unstressed vowel, /l/ or /ə(r)/.
>
> *narrow narrower narrowest
>
>   simple simpler simplest
>
>   clever cleverer cleverest
>
>   quiet quieter quietest*
>
> With many two-syllable adjectives (e.g. *polite, common*), *-er/-est* and *more/most* are both possible. With others (including adjectives ending in *-ing, -ed,
>   -ful* and *-less*), only *more/most* is possible. In general, the structure with *more/most* is becoming more common. To find out the normal comparative and
>   superlative for a particular two-syllable adjective, check in a good dictionary.

*Fickle* is pronounced with an unstressed final /əl/, so Swan would allow it to qualify for *fickler,* although as he says, "the structure with *more/most* is becoming more common."